# Java + ImageMagick: how to figure out height of text based on width?

Tags: java, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using ImageMagick with Java in my project.
I have a command:

```
 convert -background lightblue  -fill blue  -font Tahoma -pointsize 36 -size 320x caption:'This is a very long caption line.' caption.gif
```

This command will create an image named "caption.gif" 
The image's width is 320px. 
Is there any way that I can figure out the image's height without creating image. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
convert -font Tahoma -pointsize 36 -size 320x caption:'This is a very long caption line.' -format "%h" info:
88
```